# SQL: Pulling first and last date entry date from a series with repeated entries, separating blocks that aren't continuous

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, t-sql, grouping

Apologies for the title - couldn't think of one that matches what I want to do!

So I have data that has ID values, Rooms, and entry/exit date/times for those rooms. Sometimes the data entry isn't great and the ID exits and enters the same room, creating a break, which is what I'd like to remove in order to get a continuous period that they're in the room.

I can manage to do this when there is only one "block" of date/times using

```
RANK() (PARTITION BY TicketNo, Room ORDER BY Entered_DTTM asc) as [RankbyEntered_DTTM]
and
RANK() (PARTITION BY TicketNo, Room ORDER BY Exit_DTTM desc) as [RankbyExit_DTTM]
```

In 2 sub-queries to get the earliest entry and latest exit, then using Rank = 1 to join these back to the original table, but if an ID has 2 separate periods then it doesn't take into account the gap in the middle.

An example of the data (with the ranks I've used to get half-way there) is as such:

| TicketNo | Room | Entered_DTTM | Exit_DTTM | RankbyEntered_DTTM | RankbyExit_DTTM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 65768 | A | 05/01/2019 18:55 | 05/01/2019 19:30 | 1 | 1 |
| 65768 | B | 05/01/2019 19:30 | 05/01/2019 19:35 | 1 | 5 |
| 65768 | B | 05/01/2019 19:35 | 05/01/2019 20:18 | 2 | 4 |
| 65768 | C | 05/01/2019 20:18 | 05/01/2019 20:34 | 1 | 1 |
| 65768 | D | 05/01/2019 20:34 | 05/01/2019 20:59 | 1 | 1 |
| 65768 | E | 05/01/2019 20:59 | 05/01/2019 21:15 | 1 | 2 |
| 65768 | E | 05/01/2019 21:15 | 05/01/2019 21:20 | 2 | 1 |
| 65768 | B | 05/01/2019 21:20 | 05/01/2019 21:22 | 3 | 3 |
| 65768 | B | 05/01/2019 21:22 | 05/01/2019 21:23 | 4 | 2 |
| 65768 | B | 05/01/2019 21:23 | 05/01/2019 21:37 | 5 | 1 |

and this is how I'd like to get it:

| TicketNo | Room | Entered_DTTM | Exit_DTTM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 65768 | A | 05/01/2019 18:55 | 05/01/2019 19:30 |
| 65768 | B | 05/01/2019 19:30 | 05/01/2019 20:18 |
| 65768 | C | 05/01/2019 20:18 | 05/01/2019 20:34 |
| 65768 | D | 05/01/2019 20:34 | 05/01/2019 20:59 |
| 65768 | E | 05/01/2019 20:59 | 05/01/2019 21:20 |
| 65768 | B | 05/01/2019 21:20 | 05/01/2019 21:37 |

But I'm stuck getting this for Room B:

| TicketNo | Room | Entered_DTTM | Exit_DTTM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 65768 | B | 05/01/2019 19:30 | 05/01/2019 21:37 |

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Search "gaps and islands" problems. There's also plenty of questions tagged with it: [[tag:gaps-and-islands]]

Answer (score 1):

You data perfectly tiles.  If this is the case, then you can use a "two-lag()" approach:

```
select ticket_no, room, entered_dttm,
       lead(entered_dttm, 1, max_exit_dttm) over (partition by ticket_no order by entered_dttm) as exit_dttm
from (select t.*,
             lag(room) over (partition by ticket_no order by entered_dttm) as prev_room,
             max(exit_dttm) over (partition by ticket_no) as max_exit_dttm
      from t
     ) t
where prev_room is null or prev_room <> room;
```

Unlike other flavors of the gaps-and-islands problem, this provides a solution without aggregation, which can be a win for performance.  Of course, it depends on the time frames perfectly tiling as in your sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative that uses a SUM aggregation to build the groups within the TicketNo value and then finds the MIN/MAX dates within:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp (TicketNo int,Room varchar(4), Entered_DTTM datetime, Exit_DTTM datetime)
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES
(65768,'A','05/01/2019 18:55','05/01/2019 19:30'),
(65768,'B','05/01/2019 19:30','05/01/2019 19:35'),
(65768,'B','05/01/2019 19:35','05/01/2019 20:18'),
(65768,'C','05/01/2019 20:18','05/01/2019 20:34'),
(65768,'D','05/01/2019 20:34','05/01/2019 20:59'),
(65768,'E','05/01/2019 20:59','05/01/2019 21:15'),
(65768,'E','05/01/2019 21:15','05/01/2019 21:20'),
(65768,'B','05/01/2019 21:20','05/01/2019 21:22'),
(65768,'B','05/01/2019 21:22','05/01/2019 21:23'),
(65768,'B','05/01/2019 21:23','05/01/2019 21:37')

SELECT TicketNo, Room, MIN(Entered_DTTM) Entered_DTTM, MAX(Exit_DTTM) Exit_DTTM
FROM
(
    SELECT *, SUM(CASE WHEN Room <> LG_PREV OR LG_PREV IS NULL THEN 1 END) OVER(ORDER BY Entered_DTTM) Grp
    FROM
    (
        select *,  LAG(Room,1) OVER(PARTITION BY TicketNo ORDER BY Entered_DTTM) LG_PREV
        from #tmp
    ) T
) O
GROUP BY GRP, TicketNo,Room
```